# Only display min and max values in each row with geom_text

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I made this graph:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

heatmap_branquesCAT <- ggplot(varIPI_branques_CAT_long, aes(x = time, y = branques, fill=scaled_value)) +
  geom_tile(aes(width=31)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(values, 1)), family="serif", color="black", size=4) +
  scale_x_date(expand=c(0,0), breaks = "1 months", labels=date_format("%b %y")
               # limits = c(as.Date("2023/01/01"), NA)) +
              ) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0), labels=c("Subministrament d'aigua", "Indústries d'alimentació i begudes", "Altres indústries manufactureres", 
                                           "Materials i equips elèctrics, electrònics i òptics", "Energia elèctrica", 
                                           "Fabricació de productes farmacèutics", "Índex general (IPI)", "Indústries extractives",
                                           "Indústries manufactureres", "Fabricació de maquinària i equips mecànics", "Metal·lúrgia i fabricació de productes metàl·lics",
                                           "Fabricació d'altres productes minerals no metàl·lics", "Indústries del paper", "Fabricació productes cautxú i matèries plàstiques",
                                           "Indústries químiques", "Indústries tèxtils",
                                           "Fabricació de material de transport")) +
  labs(title = "Índex de Producció Industrial",
       subtitle = "% de variació interanual",
       x = "", 
       y = " ",
       caption = "Font: Idescat.") +
    scale_fill_gradient2(
      low = "#CC3300",
      mid = "white",
      high = "#66CC00",
   #   midpoint = 0, 
      limits = range(varIPI_branques_CAT_long$scaled_value)) +
  guides(color=guide_legend(title="")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  tema +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size=12, colour = "black"), 
  legend.position="none") 

heatmap_branquesCAT
```

How can I change geom_text so it only shows the text for the minimum and maximum value of each `branques`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subsetted data in `geom_text` to only show the `range` of `values` per `branques`. I've removed `+ tema` in your code since it's not provided.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

ggplot(varIPI_branques_CAT_long, aes(x = time, y = branques, fill=scaled_value)) +
  geom_tile(aes(width=31)) +
  geom_text(data = group_by(varIPI_branques_CAT_long, branques) %>% filter(values %in% range(values)), aes(label = round(values, 1)), family="serif", color="black", size=4) +
  scale_x_date(expand=c(0,0), breaks = "1 months", labels=date_format("%b %y")) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0), labels=c("Subministrament d'aigua", "Indústries d'alimentació i begudes", "Altres indústries manufactureres", 
                                           "Materials i equips elèctrics, electrònics i òptics", "Energia elèctrica", 
                                           "Fabricació de productes farmacèutics", "Índex general (IPI)", "Indústries extractives",
                                           "Indústries manufactureres", "Fabricació de maquinària i equips mecànics", "Metal·lúrgia i fabricació de productes metàl·lics",
                                           "Fabricació d'altres productes minerals no metàl·lics", "Indústries del paper", "Fabricació productes cautxú i matèries plàstiques",
                                           "Indústries químiques", "Indústries tèxtils",
                                           "Fabricació de material de transport")) +
  labs(title = "Índex de Producció Industrial",
       subtitle = "% de variació interanual",
       x = "", 
       y = " ",
       caption = "Font: Idescat.") +
  scale_fill_gradient2(
    low = "#CC3300",
    mid = "white",
    high = "#66CC00",
    limits = range(varIPI_branques_CAT_long$scaled_value)) +
  guides(color=guide_legend(title="")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size=12, colour = "black"), 
        legend.position="none")
```

[image: geom_text_range]

#### Data from your previous post

```
varIPI_branques_CAT_long <- structure(list(time = structure(c(19083, 19113, 19144, 19174, 
                                  19205, 19236, 19266, 19297, 19327, 19358, 19389, 19417, 19448, 
                                  18993, 19024, 19052, 19083, 19113, 19144, 19174, 19205, 19236, 
                                  19266, 19297, 19327, 19358, 19389, 19417, 19448, 18993, 19024
), class = "Date"), branques = c("Indústries extractives", "Indústries extractives", 
                                 "Indústries extractives", "Indústries extractives", "Indústries extractives", 
                                 "Indústries extractives", "Indústries extractives", "Indústries extractives", 
                                 "Indústries extractives", "Indústries extractives", "Indústries extractives", 
                                 "Indústries extractives", "Indústries extractives", "Indústries manufactureres", 
                                 "Indústries manufactureres", "Indústries manufactureres", "Indústries manufactureres", 
                                 "Indústries manufactureres", "Indústries manufactureres", "Indústries manufactureres", 
                                 "Indústries manufactureres", "Indústries manufactureres", "Indústries manufactureres", 
                                 "Indústries manufactureres", "Indústries manufactureres", "Indústries manufactureres", 
                                 "Indústries manufactureres", "Indústries manufactureres", "Indústries manufactureres", 
                                 "alimentació", "alimentació"), values = c(-17.2, -12, 0.6, 
                                                                           -6, 8.6, 7.5, 10, 37.1, 26.1, 28.3, 14, 16.8, -9.4, 0.8, 3.1, 
                                                                           2.5, -2.7, 6.4, 1.9, -2.9, 1.5, 2.5, 0.1, -1.9, -0.1, 5.3, -1.7, 
                                                                           1.8, -6.8, 4.6, 4.6), scaled_value = structure(c(-0.486164571662395, 
                                                                                                                            -0.269301398928164, 0.256174750389396, -0.0190746611578974, 0.589810400749752, 
                                                                                                                            0.543935498825203, 0.648196639562814, 1.77838740515852, 1.31963838591303, 
                                                                                                                            1.41138818976213, 0.815014464742992, 0.931786942369116, -0.160869812561049, 
                                                                                                                            0.0939546003127367, 0.338515461609155, 0.274716976053568, -0.278203232094857, 
                                                                                                                            0.689407132164886, 0.21091849049798, -0.299469393946719, 0.168386166794255, 
                                                                                                                            0.274716976053568, 0.019523033831218, -0.193138584687407, -0.00174312802064446, 
                                                                                                                            0.572443241979642, -0.171872422835544, 0.200285409572049, -0.714159550058037, 
                                                                                                                            0.59745871515621, 0.59745871515621), dim = c(31L, 1L))), row.names = 20:50, class = "data.frame")
```